# Can I tracks control flow in debugger?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

With using `bt (backtrace)` instruction in gdb,
We can roughly see the location that control flow have been through.

However, It is available only when the branch instruction is `call`.
(which saves the return address in stack.)

I'm curious about whether I can track `jmp` in the similar manner.
As you know, `jmp` does not saves return address...


***My situation:***
More precisely, I'm trouble in below situation.

```
0x9230  push   %ebx                     // Where %ebx comes from?
0x9231  mov    0x8(%esp),%eax
```

I want to know in where the *%ebx* value comes from.
In ***somewhere***, control flow switched to here using `jmp`.
I want to know where ***somewhere*** is.

***Question:***
*Is there any way to track the instruction jmp?*
  *(Or is there any possible application I can use?)*

Comment: Use single-stepping.

Comment: @Barmar Of course I know. But in this case, the program is too huge to use `single stepping`. I'm wondering if there's an command/functionality to track it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's nothing that does what you want in gdb.

Comment: is your code cross platform which you could compile and run on Windows too or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> More precisely, I'm trouble in below situation.
>   `0x9230  push   %ebx                     // Where %ebx comes from?`

In a situation like this, *reverse* debugger is likely to be most useful.

Last time I tried it, [rr](https://rr-project.org/) worked wonders for answering "where did this come from?" questions.

Here you would simply use `reverse-stepi` until you find an instruction that updated `%ebx`.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is only with direct `jmp` family (`jmp`,`jz`,`jnz`,...), you can disassemble your code and check which jump instruction comes there.

Best commercial disassembler is [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml) which has inside debugger too. But getting it be me tricky. But other disassemblers normally can show direct jump references too, so it may be good to try a free one in Linux.

But if your jump is indirect like `jmp [eax]`, you need to find it through debugging. As far as I remember, Windows debuggers like olydbg or X64dbg can show source of indirect jump when it happens, But these are Windows only.